# Shrink Dynamic VDI to real size

Tags: virtualbox, disk-space

My Dynamic VDI has occupied 56.2 GB space on the NTFS partition with Windows 7 Host. I am running a Ubuntu Server on the machine and it only occuipies 4.1 GB

Command: df -h Shows

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             2.0T  4.1G  1.9T   1% /
none                  4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                  235M  4.0K  235M   1% /dev
tmpfs                  50M  512K   49M   2% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  246M  4.0K  246M   1% /run/shm
none                  100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sdb1             2.0T   11G  1.9T   1% /var/dev
/home/starx/.Private  2.0T  4.1G  1.9T   1% /home/starx
```

How to shrink this 56.2 GB to 4.1 GB which is the real size?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to fill the unused space with zeros, then ask VB to shrink the disk.

Eg: as root in Linux:
`dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024k of=/bigfile; rm -f /bigfile`

Then shut the machine down and run:
`VBoxManage modifyhd diskfile.vdi --compact`

With most of the disk zero-filled it should shrink down to something close to 4GB.